# React Slick Slider slickGoTo - Custom Slider Nav Buttons

Tags: reactjs, slick.js, react-slick

I'm new to react and I'm trying to make a custom react slick slider navigator for my sliders.

I've 2 separate sliders that are linked by the `asNavFor` method and I want my buttons to change the sliders to the index of the button clicked.

I'll leave my code bellow.

```
import { useState, useRef, useEffect } from 'react';

import '../css/KioskSlides.css';

import frame from '../img/frame.png';

import Slider from 'react-slick';

import "slick-carousel/slick/slick.css"; 
import "slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.css";

import kioskSlide1  from "../data/kiosk-slider1";

import {FontAwesomeIcon} from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import {faSun, faCameraRetro, faDownload, faBus, faPeopleLine, faKitMedical } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';

function KioskSlider(){

    const [nav1, setNav1] = useState();
    const [nav2, setNav2] = useState();

    const settings = {
        dots: false,
        fade: true,
        infinite: true,
        speed: 500,
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1
    };

    const settings1 = {
        arrows: false,
        dots: false,
        fade: true,
        infinite: true,
        speed: 500,
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1
    };

    const kiosk1 = kioskSlide1.map(slide => {
        return(
            <>
            <div className='servicos-slide w-full items-center' >
                <div className='w-6/12 px-6 '>
                    <h1 className='text-[#333] text-[28px] font-semibold '>{slide.title}</h1>
                    <p className='text-[#333] text-[22px] '>{slide.text}</p>
                </div>
                
            </div>
            </>
        )
    })
    
    const kioskImg1 = kioskSlide1.map(slide => {
        return(

            <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: slide.media }}></div>
        )
    })

    const refSlide1 = (slider1) => setNav1(slider1)
    const refSlide2 = (slider2) => setNav2(slider2)

    
    
    return(
        <>
        <div id="servicos" className='w-full h-[910px] flex items-center '>
            <div className='container mx-auto  items-center'>
                <div className='w-full'>
                    <h2 className='text-[#333] text-[44px] font-bold pl-9 mb-8'>Todos os serviços<br></br> num só portal</h2>
                    <Slider {...settings} className='w-full pl-3' asNavFor={nav2} ref={refSlide1} >
                        {kiosk1}
                    </Slider>
                    <div className='w-6/12 px-10 mt-12 '>
                        <button className='w-[165px] h-[45px] p-2 mr-2 mb-8 text-white bg-[#D6004C] active:text-[#D6004C] active:bg-white active:border-2 active:border-[#D6004C] hover:text-[#D6004C] hover:bg-white hover:border-2 hover:border-[#D6004C] text-lg text-center font-medium rounded-3xl inline-block'  > <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faSun} /> Meteorologia</button>
                        <button className='w-[165px] h-[45px] p-2 mr-2 mb-8 text-white bg-[#D6004C] active:text-[#D6004C] active:bg-white active:border-2 active:border-[#D6004C] hover:text-[#D6004C] hover:bg-white hover:border-2 hover:border-[#D6004C] text-lg text-center font-medium rounded-3xl inline-block' onClick={/* go to slide number 2*/ } > <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCameraRetro}/> Galeria</button>
                        <button className='w-[165px] h-[45px] p-2 mr-2 mb-8 text-white bg-[#D6004C] active:text-[#D6004C] active:bg-white active:border-2 active:border-[#D6004C] hover:text-[#D6004C] hover:bg-white hover:border-2 hover:border-[#D6004C] text-lg text-center font-medium rounded-3xl inline-block'  > <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faDownload}/> Downloads</button>
                        <button className='w-[165px] h-[45px] p-2 mr-2 mb-8 text-white bg-[#D6004C] active:text-[#D6004C] active:bg-white active:border-2 active:border-[#D6004C] hover:text-[#D6004C] hover:bg-white hover:border-2 hover:border-[#D6004C] text-lg text-center font-medium rounded-3xl inline-block'  > <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faBus}/> Transportes</button>
                        <button className='w-[165px] h-[45px] p-2 mr-2 mb-8 text-white bg-[#D6004C] active:text-[#D6004C] active:bg-white active:border-2 active:border-[#D6004C] hover:text-[#D6004C] hover:bg-white hover:border-2 hover:border-[#D6004C] text-lg text-center font-medium rounded-3xl inline-block'  > <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPeopleLine}/> Filas</button>
                        <button className='w-[165px] h-[45px] p-2 mr-2 mb-8 text-white bg-[#D6004C] active:text-[#D6004C] active:bg-white active:border-2 active:border-[#D6004C] hover:text-[#D6004C] hover:bg-white hover:border-2 hover:border-[#D6004C] text-lg text-center font-medium rounded-3xl inline-block'  > <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faKitMedical}/> Farmácias</button>
                    </div>
                    <img src={frame} alt="" className='w-[348px] h-auto z-40 absolute top-[88%] right-[20%] '/>
                    
                    <Slider {...settings1} className="imgSlider w-[237px] h-[421px] right-[22.9%] top-[98.5%] " asNavFor={nav1} ref={refSlide2} >
                        {kioskImg1}
                    </Slider>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        </>
    )
}

export default KioskSlider;
```

How should I target both sliders in order to change their index on each button click?

Print for better explanation.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7VBS0.png)

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: So you want custom slider next and previous buttons with event right?

Comment: @PriyenMehta what i need is a way to add a onClick event on each button that changes the sliders index, ex. button 2 is clicked, both sliders go to 2 slide.
i've added a print of what it looks like right now

Comment: okay, I will help you to backward and forward event by index than you can implement in your code as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to pass your event like this and NextArrowWrapper and PrevArrowWrapper are just icons.

```
const settings = {
 ...styles[deviceType],
 infinite: true,
 slidesToScroll: 1,
 initialSlide: 0,
 autoplay: true,
 autoplaySpeed: 3000,
 nextArrow: <NextArrowWrapper onNextClick={onNextClick} />,
 prevArrow: <PrevArrowWrapper onPreviousClick={onPreviousClick} />,
 dotsClass: classNames('slick-dots', theme),
};
```

Two events: **You have to use slider ref current object for prev and next event, Like this.**

```
const onPreviousClick = () => {
 sliderRef.current.slickPrev();
};

const onNextClick = () => {
 sliderRef.current.slickNext();
};
```

Pass your ref in slider like this:

```
<Slider ref={sliderRef} {...settings}>
```

Thanks, I hope it will help you :).